# Numpy multidimensional array slicing

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexing, numpy

Suppose I have defined a 3x3x3 numpy array with

```
x = numpy.arange(27).reshape((3, 3, 3))
```

Now, I can get an array containing the (0,1) element of each 3x3 subarray with `x[:, 0, 1]`, which returns `array([ 1, 10, 19])`.  What if I have a tuple (m,n) and want to retrieve the (m,n) element of each subarray(0,1) stored in a tuple?

For example, suppose that I have `t = (0, 1)`.  I tried `x[:, t]`, but it doesn't have the right behaviour - it returns rows 0 and 1 of each subarray.  The simplest solution I have found is

```
x.transpose()[tuple(reversed(t))].transpose()
```

but I am sure there must be a better way.  Of course, in this case, I could do `x[:, t[0], t[1]]`, but that can't be generalised to the case where I don't know how many dimensions `x` and `t` have.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can create the index tuple first:

```
index = (numpy.s_[:],)+t 
x[index]
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for the help (you too, wim).  I found more examples for s_ and slice at [scipy](http://www.scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List).  I think I looked through that list before, but didn't see anything that looked relevant.

Answer (score 4):

HYRY solution is correct, but I have always found numpy's `r_`, `c_` and `s_` index tricks to be a bit strange looking.  So here is the equivalent thing using a `slice` object:

```
x[(slice(None),) + t]
```

That single argument to slice is  the stop position (i.e. `None` meaning all in the same way that `x[:]` is equivalent to `x[None:None]`)